# Как посимвольно вывести переменную?

Tags: bash, cmd, консоль

Помогите написать сценарий, который выводит посимвольно строковую переменную

Пример без цикла:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set /p var="enter the string: "
call :print_by_chars "%var%"
pause
goto :eof
:print_by_chars
set "t=%~1"
if "%t%"=="" exit /b
echo(%t:~,1%
call :print_by_chars "%t:~1%"
exit /b
```

Необходимо решить через цикл for.

Comment: Юрий, зачем такая агрессия? Что плохого если я задал вопрос? В конце концов этот сервис для этого и предназначен. Плох тот программист который не задаёт вопросов. Я же не прошу вас сдавать за меня тот или иной предмет. Если вы не хотите помочь, зачем пишете это?

Comment: Это не агрессия. А сессия, видимо близко.  
@fedor-sg, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.  
@fedor-sg, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Comment: И вопрос вы не задали, у вас вместо вопроса задание выполнить, притом в повелительном наклонении.

Comment: Сложно здесь общаться оказывается :) И "сессия", как вы указали выше, здесь не причем. Я не задаю вопроса, где необходимо сделать за меня курсовую и считаю, что вопрос допустим, т.к. он связан с изучением программирования. Здесь я хочу просто увидеть наброски решения это задачи. И вообще, если посмотреть на вопросы этого сайта, можно смело отправлять в мусор некоторые из них, т.к. это "помощь студентам в сдачи сессии" :) Тем не менее, если вопрос не соответствует правилам форума, можно просто удалить вопрос и конфликт будет исчерпан :)

Comment: @fedor-sg, если у вас есть вопрос, так задайте его. Никто не против помочь в решении конкретной проблемы, натолкнуть на решение, если есть "затык" даже в учебном задании. Вот таких вопросов, как у вас, действительно множество. Большинство таких "вопросов" задаются в надежде на халяву. И такие вопросы действительно удаляются, с отсрочкой на исправление вопроса автором.

Comment: У меня есть идеи, но я сомневаюсь в реализации. Юрий, как вы думаете, если перефразировать так "Как вывести строку посимвольно в цикле for?".

Comment: @fedor-sg опять же это очень общий вопрос, который никоим образом не раскрывает суть того, сделали вы что-либо и требуется помощь или же вы хотите получить готовое решение.

Comment: Как оказалось, вопрос намного сложнее поставить, чем ответ:) Может, начать так "Как задавать правильно вопрос?":) Шутка, конечно, но с долей правды:)

Comment: @fedor-sg, IMHO реальная проблема в том, что никто здесь (я тоже) не помнит этот язык сценариев.

Comment: при чём тут тэг линукс?

Comment: Не пишите "помогите" не здоровайтесь. Представьте, что вы пишите в энциклопедию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fedor-sg,

> Как вывести строку посимвольно в цикле for?

Можно запустить цикл от 0 до "очень много" и прочитать строку поиндкесно.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set word=123
for /L %%a in (0, 1, 100500) do (
set w=!word:~%%a,1!
if [!w!] == [] (goto :ok)
echo !w!
)
:ok
```

И если строка не кончилась, запустить цикл еще раз. В любом случае, насколько такие танцы приемлемы, решать вам.

Comment: Юрий, спасибо большое! Американские друзья советовали прибегнуть к такому:
set "char=%st:~0,1%" и set "string=%st:~1%". И так до тех пор, пока строка не станет пустой. Я пытался сделать for /l %%a in (0,0,0) do, но ничего не выходило. Интересный способ :)